# How to read xml data as shown below in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to read the bold words as the column names in the dataframe and the string following the bold letters as the value for that particular row.

```
<posts>

<**row Id**="5" PostTypeId="1" **CreationDate**="2014-05-13T23:58:30.457" **Score**="7" ViewCount="315" **Body**="<p>I've always been interested in machine learning, but I can't figure out one thing about starting out with a simple "Hello World" example - how can I avoid hard-coding behavior?</p><p>For example, if I wanted to "teach" a bot how to avoid randomly placed obstacles, I couldn't just use relative motion, because the obstacles move around, but I don't want to hard code, say, distance, because that ruins the whole point of machine learning.</p><p>Obviously, randomly generating code would be impractical, so how could I do this?</p>" **OwnerUserId**="5" LastActivityDate="2014-05-14T00:36:31.077" Title="How can I do simple machine learning without hard-coding behavior?" Tags="<machine-learning>" AnswerCount="1" CommentCount="1" FavoriteCount="1" ClosedDate="2014-05-14T14:40:25.950"/>

<**row Id**="7" **PostTypeId**="1" **AcceptedAnswerId**="10" CreationDate="2014-05-14T00:11:06.457" Score="2" ViewCount="297" Body="<p>As a researcher and instructor, I'm looking for open-source books (or similar materials) that provide a relatively thorough overview of data science from an applied perspective. To be clear, I'm especially interested in a thorough overview that provides material suitable for a college-level course, not particular pieces or papers.</p>" OwnerUserId="36" LastEditorUserId="97" LastEditDate="2014-05-16T13:45:00.237"LastActivityDate="2014-05-16T13:45:00.237" Title="What open-source books (or other materials) provide a relatively thorough overview of data science?" Tags="<education><open-source>" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="4" FavoriteCount="1" **ClosedDate**="2014-05-14T08:40:54.950"/>

</posts>
```

Comment: Considering using the StackExchange API instead of screen scraping.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow

Comment: No, it's not screen scraping. The dataset have been downloaded from the stack exchange website, and it contains these xml format files. Suggest the way to get it inside the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Also, SO is not a code writing service.  You need to show us any ideas, efforts you have taken towards attempting your question.

Comment: Try parsing with `etree` and then map values to dataframe. Return with any issues.

Comment: @ANURAGMODI regardless, the StackExchange API may be more useful to you than "file-scraping".